# How do I access the QLineEdit widget I added to this Qt example?

Tags: c++, qt

I followed this Qt [tutorial](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_SignalsSlotsGui.php) on signals and slots, including the part where you delete the connection you can automatically make in Qt Designer and instead type in the `connect` function by hand in mainwindow.cpp. I wanted to make my own slot where moving the tutorial's `QSlider` changed a `QLineEdit` I added, so I did this:

1. I added a `QLineEdit` widget named `lineEdit` to my `mainwindow.ui` in Qt Designer.
2. In the `MainWindow` class definition in `mainwindow.h`, I added this at the bottom of the class.

   ```
   public slots:
     void changeLineEdit() {
     ui->lineEdit->setText("Value was changed");
   }
   ```
3. In the `MainWindow` constructor in mainwindow.cpp, I added this:  (`ui->horizontalSlider` was the QSlider made in the tutorial.)

   ```
   connect(ui->horizontalSlider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), SLOT(changeLineEdit()));
   ```

When I tried to build the project, I got **9** errors, one of them being "use of undefined type `Ui::MainWindow`". What did I do wrong in this edit?
The `MainWindow` class definition has a private pointer `Ui::Mainwindow *ui`, so I thought the slot definition would access the `ui` pointer and therefore the `lineEdit` widget included there.

Comment: Normally you implement your slots in the cpp file. Well at least I do. ***use of undefined type 'Ui::MainWindow*** Means since you implemented it in the header you will have to add the include Ui::MainWindow in your header instead of just your cpp file.

Comment: @drescherjm Oh I forgot about that. Ya, I had a `UI::MainWindow` declared like in the tutorial, but since I defined my slot there, I had to also include `#include "ui_mainwindow.h"` in that header file to actually initialize it. Thanks, I'll implement it in a .cpp next time. I can accept your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement your slot in your header make sure you include the header for `UI::MainWindow` in your header for your class as well. Normally I would implement my slots in the `cpp` file instead however that is not a requirement.